# How to use scipy.interpolate.interpn function with xarray (3d), to fill nan gaps? Current Error [The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending]

Tags: numpy, scipy, 3d, nan, python-xarray

I am a bit frustrated as I could not find a solution to my problem which seems easy to do in r with package gapfill but here in python it is more difficult.

Coming to my problem: I have an xarray (3d) with the dimensions latitude, longitude and time. What I want is to interpolate nan values in each raster/array (caused by cloud and other distortions). The nan values form blocks (due to the clouds) and are sometimes relatively big. My idea is to interpolate not only with the neighbouring pixels of each timestep but also with the timesteps from before and after (the assumption is that the pixel some days before and some days after have a realtively similar value as the landcoverage is not changing so fast). My aim is to do a linear interpolation over time with the same pixel position. (how many timesteps before and after is also something where I am not sure how I can define that in the interpn function?)

I found different options to do that, however non was working yet. The most promising method I found is from the package scipy with the interpolate.interpn function. This function uses a numpy array not an xarray. My attempt:

```
#change from xarray to numpy 
my array_np = my array.to_numpy()

# lable dimensions (what is done when building a numpy with meshgrid)

x = array_np [0]
y = array_np [1]
z = array_np [2]

#get index of nan values

nanIndex= np.isnan(array_np ).nonzero()
nanIndex

#name dimensions of nan values 

xc= nanIndex[0] 
yc= nanIndex[1]
zc= nanIndex[2] 

# For using the scipy interpolate. interpn function: 
# points = the regular grid  - in my case x,y,z
# values = the data on the regular grid - in my case my array (my_array_np)
# point_nan = the point that is evaluate in the 3D grid - in my case xc, y,c, zy

points = (x, y, z) # dimensions
points_nan = (xc, yc, zc) #nandimensions

print(interpolate.interpn(points, my_array_np, points_nan))
```

What I get now as an error is:

```
"The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending"
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks for you help in advance! If you have another other solutions which also solves my probelem beside scipy I am also happy for help!

This is a how my array looks:

```
array([[[      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 279.64   , 282.16998,
         279.66998],
        [277.62   , 277.52   , 277.88   , ..., 281.75998, 281.72   ,
         281.66   ],
        [277.38   , 277.75   , 277.88998, ..., 281.75998, 281.75998,
         280.91998],
        ...,
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 280.72998, 280.33   ,
         280.94   ],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan]],
       [[      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 272.22   , 271.54   ,
         271.02   ],
        [280.02   , 280.44998, 281.18   , ..., 271.47998, 271.88   ,
         272.03   ],
        [280.32   , 281.     , 281.27   , ..., 270.83   , 271.58   ,
         272.03   ],
        ...,
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 290.34   , 290.25   ,
         288.365  ],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan]],

       [[      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [276.44998, 276.19998, 276.19   , ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [276.50998, 276.79   , 276.58   , ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        ...,
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan]],

       ...,

       [[      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 276.38998, 276.44   ,
         275.72998],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 276.55   , 276.81   ,
         276.72998],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 279.74   , 277.11   ,
         276.97   ],
        ...,
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan]],

       [[      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 277.38   , 278.08   ,
         277.79   ],
        [279.66998, 280.00998, 283.13   , ..., 277.34   , 277.41998,
         277.62   ],
        [      nan, 277.41   , 277.41   , ..., 277.825  , 277.31   ,
         277.52   ],
        ...,
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ..., 276.52   ,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan]],

       [[      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        ...,
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan],
        [      nan,       nan,       nan, ...,       nan,       nan,
               nan]]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

`interpn` cannot be used to fill gaps in a regular grid - interpn is a fast method for interpolating a full regular grid (with no gaps) to different coordinates.

To fill missing values with N-dimensional interpolation, use of the scipy interpolation methods for [unstructured N-dimensional data](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation).

Since you're interpolating *to* a regular grid, I'll demo the use of [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata):

```py
import xarray as xr, pandas as pd, numpy as np, scipy.interpolate

# create dummy data
x = y = z = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
da = xr.DataArray(
    np.sin(x).reshape(-1, 1, 1) * np.cos(y).reshape(1, -1, 1) + z.reshape(1, 1, -1),
    dims=['x', 'y', 'z'],
    coords=[x, y, z],
)


# randomly fill with NaNs
da = da.where(np.random.random(size=da.shape) > 0.1)
```

This looks like the following

```py
In [11]: da
Out[11]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 5, y: 5, z: 5)>
array([[[0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ]],

       [[0.24740396, 0.49740396, 0.74740396, 0.99740396,        nan],
        [       nan, 0.48971277,        nan, 0.98971277, 1.23971277],
        [0.2171174 , 0.4671174 , 0.7171174 , 0.9671174 , 1.2171174 ],
        [0.18102272, 0.43102272, 0.68102272, 0.93102272, 1.18102272],
        [       nan, 0.38367293, 0.63367293, 0.88367293, 1.13367293]],

       [[0.47942554,        nan, 0.97942554, 1.22942554, 1.47942554],
        [0.46452136, 0.71452136, 0.96452136, 1.21452136, 1.46452136],
        [0.42073549, 0.67073549, 0.92073549, 1.17073549,        nan],
        [0.35079033, 0.60079033, 0.85079033, 1.10079033, 1.35079033],
        [       nan, 0.50903472, 0.75903472,        nan, 1.25903472]],

       [[0.68163876, 0.93163876, 1.18163876, 1.43163876, 1.68163876],
        [0.66044826, 0.91044826,        nan, 1.41044826, 1.66044826],
        [0.59819429, 0.84819429, 1.09819429, 1.34819429,        nan],
        [       nan, 0.74874749, 0.99874749, 1.24874749,        nan],
        [0.36829099, 0.61829099, 0.86829099, 1.11829099, 1.36829099]],

       [[0.84147098, 1.09147098,        nan, 1.59147098, 1.84147098],
        [0.81531169, 1.06531169, 1.31531169, 1.56531169, 1.81531169],
        [0.73846026, 0.98846026, 1.23846026, 1.48846026,        nan],
        [0.61569495, 0.86569495, 1.11569495, 1.36569495, 1.61569495],
        [0.45464871, 0.70464871, 0.95464871,        nan, 1.45464871]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0
  * y        (y) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0
  * z        (z) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0
```

To use an unstructured scipy interpolator, you must convert the gridded data with missing values to vectors of 1D points with no missing values:

```py
# ravel all points and find the valid ones
points = da.data.ravel()
valid = ~np.isnan(points)
points_valid = points[valid]

# construct arrays of (x, y, z) points, masked to only include the valid points
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
xx, yy, zz = xx.ravel(), yy.ravel(), zz.ravel()
xxv = xx[valid]
yyv = yy[valid]
zzv = zz[valid]

# feed these into the interpolator, and also provide the target grid
interpolated = scipy.interpolate.griddata(np.stack([xxv, yyv, zzv]).T, points_valid, (xx, yy, zz), method="linear")

# reshape to match the original array and replace the DataArray values with
# the interpolated data
da.values = interpolated.reshape(da.shape)
```

This results in the array being filled

```py
In [32]: da
Out[32]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 5, y: 5, z: 5)>
array([[[0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ],
        [0.        , 0.25      , 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ]],

       [[0.24740396, 0.49740396, 0.74740396, 0.99740396, 1.23971277],
        [0.23226068, 0.48971277, 0.73226068, 0.98971277, 1.23971277],
        [0.2171174 , 0.4671174 , 0.7171174 , 0.9671174 , 1.2171174 ],
        [0.18102272, 0.43102272, 0.68102272, 0.93102272, 1.18102272],
        [0.12276366, 0.38367293, 0.63367293, 0.88367293, 1.13367293]],

       [[0.47942554, 0.71452136, 0.97942554, 1.22942554, 1.47942554],
        [0.46452136, 0.71452136, 0.96452136, 1.21452136, 1.46452136],
        [0.42073549, 0.67073549, 0.92073549, 1.17073549, 1.40765584],
        [0.35079033, 0.60079033, 0.85079033, 1.10079033, 1.35079033],
        [0.24552733, 0.50903472, 0.75903472, 1.00903472, 1.25903472]],

       [[0.68163876, 0.93163876, 1.18163876, 1.43163876, 1.68163876],
        [0.66044826, 0.91044826, 1.16044826, 1.41044826, 1.66044826],
        [0.59819429, 0.84819429, 1.09819429, 1.34819429, 1.57184545],
        [0.48324264, 0.74874749, 0.99874749, 1.24874749, 1.48324264],
        [0.36829099, 0.61829099, 0.86829099, 1.11829099, 1.36829099]],

       [[0.84147098, 1.09147098, 1.34147098, 1.59147098, 1.84147098],
        [0.81531169, 1.06531169, 1.31531169, 1.56531169, 1.81531169],
        [0.73846026, 0.98846026, 1.23846026, 1.48846026, 1.71550332],
        [0.61569495, 0.86569495, 1.11569495, 1.36569495, 1.61569495],
        [0.45464871, 0.70464871, 0.95464871, 1.20464871, 1.45464871]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0
  * y        (y) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0
  * z        (z) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0
```

Note that this filled the complete array because the convex hull of available points covers the whole array. If this is not the case, you may need a second step using nearest neighbor or fitting a spline to the filled data.

Comment: @ Michael Delgado : Thanks so much that was working! One thing I had to change was the time dimension of the array before interpolating as otherwise I got an error "datetime must be float". Hence I changed it with: xxx = xx.astype('datetime64[D]').astype(float). 
One question because the documentation of scipy is not easy to understand for me. The nan values are now linear interpolated with values from other timesteps? Or also with its neighbouring pixels from the same timestep. If you know any link/website which explains this process well, I would really appreciate it. Thanks so much!!

Comment: it's linearly interpolated in all dimensions, treating them all equally. so yes, it's incorporating the time dimension in the interpolation as well

Comment: Ok thanks! And equally for all timesteps or just the steps before and after the nan values are occuring?

Comment: just the nearby points. if you want to fit a spline or something that's a different approach. see the scipy docs on [LinearNDInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator) and [QHull](http://www.qhull.org/) for the implementation details.

Comment: your approach works well when there are some pixels missing in a 3d array. However if there is one complete timestep missing then this approach does not work (neither with NN or with linear) - the results just looks unrealistic. Is there a chance to use your proposed method to to a linear temporal interpolation of a 3d array? (eg when one timestep/raster is missing the raster before and after are there? (I am not sure if I should make a new question for that or if the answer is easy an can be answered here as a comment?) Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is full linear interpolation in 3d. It should handle missing time steps just fine as long as there is data before and after. So unfortunately this is already doing what you’re asking and if you want to find a different algorithm that’s more a scientific question than an implementation one.