# How to do a temporal linear interpolation of a 3d array (lat,lon,time) for one missing timestep in the 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, python-xarray

I want to to a temporal linear interpolation on griddata (= xarray with dimensions: lat,lon, time), meaning that I have one timestep where there is no data but the timesteps before and after have information. I tried to use scipy.interpolate.griddata where I first created a mask layer for all the nan data and then interpolate the nans with the data which is there.

data dummy:

```
       [0.47942554, 0.48971277,  0.47942554, 0.98971277, 1.23971277],
       [0.2171174 , 0.4671174 , 0.7171174 , 0.9671174 , 1.2171174 ],
       [0.18102272, 0.43102272, 0.68102272, 0.93102272, 1.18102272],
       [0.47942554, 0.38367293, 0.63367293, 0.88367293, 1.13367293]],

       [[nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  nan, nan, nan, nan]],
       

      [[0.47942554,  0.47942554, 0.97942554, 1.22942554, 1.47942554],
       [0.46452136, 0.71452136, 0.96452136, 1.21452136, 1.46452136],
       [0.42073549, 0.67073549, 0.92073549, 1.17073549,  0.47942554],
       [0.35079033, 0.60079033, 0.85079033, 1.10079033, 1.35079033],
       [0.47942554, 0.50903472, 0.75903472, 0.47942554, 1.25903472]]])
```

what I have tried (with the help of this question: [How to use scipy.interpolate.interpn function with xarray (3d), to fill nan gaps? Current Error [The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74150690/how-to-use-scipy-interpolate-interpn-function-with-xarray-3d-to-fill-nan-gaps)) :

```
# ravel all points and find the valid ones
points = da.data.ravel()
valid = ~np.isnan(points)
points_valid = points[valid]

# construct arrays of (x, y, z) points, masked to only include the valid points
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
xx, yy, zz = xx.ravel(), yy.ravel(), zz.ravel()
xxv = xx[valid]
yyv = yy[valid]
zzv = zz[valid]

# feed these into the interpolator, and also provide the target grid
interpolated = scipy.interpolate.griddata(np.stack([xxv, yyv, zzv]).T, points_valid, (xx, yy, zz), method="linear")

# reshape to match the original array and replace the DataArray values with
# the interpolated data
da.values = interpolated.reshape(da.shape)
```

However in this approach there is no difference between spatial and temporal interpolation, because just the nearest values are used (also with linear interpolation - then just the next 3 points are taken). The problem is, that for some reason it is always using the nearest points spatially and not temporal. Therefor the spatial Interpolation looks fine, but the temporal Interpolation looks messed up. What I want is just a temporal Interpolation (without spatial neighbours).

What can I change? Please help!

Comment: Can you just use xarray’s [`xr.DataArray.interpolate_na`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.interpolate_na.html) along the time dim? I built a 3d interpolator in the other question because you specifically asked for 3d interpolation of nans, but in 1D xarray does this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

`xarray` has some interpolation tools.

Below example opens a netCDF dataset from file location `fname` and interpolates param1 and param2 on lon, lat and time.

```
with xr.open_dataset(fname) as ds:
    lat = xr.DataArray(your_lat_array, dims='z')
    lon = xr.DataArray(your_lon_array, dims='z')
    time_array = xr.DataArray(your_time_array, dims='z')
    interp_results = ds.interp(lat=lat,lon=lon,time=time_array)
    df['param1'] = interp_results['param1'].values
    df['param2'] = interp_results['param2'].values
```

I cannot tell exactly how your code looks from the dummies, but I believe above code can guide you to the right answer. For more details on interp, see xarray docs [here](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.interp.html). It inherits from `scipy.interp`

Comment: Interp interpolates the data from a full regular grid without nans to new points. It doesn’t fill nans. So I don’t think this is what the op is looking for.